# Creating folder in INTERNAL STORAGE and saving bitmap image in folder on MARSHMALLOW

Tags: android

How do I create folder in INTERNAL STORAGE and save bitmap image in folder on Android marshmallow.
I wanted to know particularly in Marshmallow... And I have given all the permission in manifest file.
Please help me out to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

In particularly Marshmallow version, Permission are need to be taken Programatically. Following is the sample code to read external storage.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_CODE);
```

In method onResultPermissionsRequest()

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
   if(requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE){
         if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                //Permission granted 
          }
          else{
               //Permission Not granted
          }

   }

}
```

Hope write similar code for various different permission. Hope this should work. In case this didn't work one thing is sure in Marshmallow need to take permissions dynamically.